# How to set a enum property with QVariant(get value from xml text node) by QObject::setProperty in qt 5(any specific version)

Tags: qt, qt5

Recently I want to reconstruct a object from xml file. a xml file looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root version="0.0.1" author="lee" modify="2020-10-03">
    <ExampleOject>
        <_id>10</_id>
        <_openType>1</_openType>
    </ExampleOject>
</Root>
```

The `_openType` in the xml is a property of `ExampleOject` and it's a enum:

```cpp
class ExampleOject
{
Q_OBJECT
Q_PROPERTY(OpenType _openType READ getType WRITE setType)
public:
  enum OpenType{BY_ID = 1, BY_NAME=2};
  Q_ENUM(Status)

  OpenType _openType;
  OpenType getType() const{return _openType;}
  void setType(const OpenType &type){_openType = type;}
};
```

After I find that property node and I read from file and set into property like:

```cpp
QString propertyName = xmlReader.name().toString();
QString propertyValue = xmlReader.readElementText();
if(!obj->setProperty(propertyName.toStdString().c_str(), QVariant(propertyValue)))
{
  return;
}
```

But this fails(QObject::setProperty returns false and ) and I looked around and one thing I get is that we can only set a enum type with int or uint, not from QString or any other.

Is there any way to set a `enum` property of a object in qt5 by `QObject::setProperty` or other method?

Answer (score 1):

For now, I achieve this in two steps:

1. When writing a property into xml, write a attribute `type="enum"` if it is a enumerate property with `QMetaProperty::isEnumType()`
2. When reading a property, check if it has a attribute `type="enum"`

So, At last my xml file looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root version="0.0.1" author="lee" modify="2020-10-03">
    <ExampleOject>
        <_id>10</_id>
        <_openType type="enum">1</_openType>
    </ExampleOject>
</Root>
```

STEP 1. the related writing codes:

```cpp
//... get _openType node
QMetaProperty metaproperty = staticMetaObject.property(i);
if(metaproperty.isEnumType())
{
 // write type = "enum" attribute into that node
}
//...
```

STEP 2. reading:

```cpp
// ... get _openType node
auto isEnum = xmlReader.attributes().value("type");
if(isEnum.toString() == QString("enum"))
{
   QString propertyValue = xmlReader.readElementText();
   qint32 enumValue = propertyValue.toInt();
   if(!obj->setProperty(propertyName.toStdString().c_str(), QVariant(enumValue)))
   {
     return;
   }
   else
   {
     QString propertyValue = xmlReader.readElementText();
     if(!obj->setProperty(propertyName.toStdString().c_str(), QVariant(propertyValue)))
     {
       return;
     }
   }
}
//...
```

Any other good ideas? This just works for me.